Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem (as in Kunen).
In $\S1$ of chapter $V$, of Kunens "Set Theory An Introduction to Independence Proofs", we are given a proof of the Löwenheim-Skolem-Tarski theorem:

$\forall B \ \forall X \subset B \ \exists A[X \subset A \subset B \land A \prec B \land |A| \leq \max(\omega,|X|)]$.

The proof basically constructs skolem functions $H_{mn}$ that are defined depending on whether $m$ is of the form $2^i \cdot 3^j \cdot 5^4$ or not (encoding a formula involving existential quantifier or not, in my understanding).
The proof ends with

It is straightforward induction on $m$ to show that $$\forall n[\text{En}(m,A,n) = \text{En}(m,B,n) \cap A^n]$$.

I know how to handle almost all cases of the induction (depending on what form $m$ takes), but I am struggling a little with the case when $\text{En}(m+1,A,n) = \text{Proj}(A,\text{En}(i,A,n+1),n)$ in the inductive step.
Here is my reasoning. We have \begin{align}\begin{aligned}\text{En}(m+1,A,n) &= \text{Proj}(A,\text{En}(i,A,n+1),n)\\
&= \text{Proj}(A,\text{En}(i,B,n+1) \cap A^{n+1},n).       \qquad(1)
\end{aligned}
\end{align}
where the last step followed by induction, since $i < m = 2^i \cdot 3^j \cdot 5^4$.
We also have \begin{align*}\text{En}(m+1,B,n) \cap A^n &= \text{Proj}(B,\text{En}(i,B,n+1),n)\\
&= \{s \in B^n: \exists t \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)(t \upharpoonright n = s)\} \cap A^n\\
&= \{s \in A^n: \exists t \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)(t \upharpoonright n = s)\}.
\end{align*}
Now, by construction of $H_{(m+1)n}$, if $t \in \text{En}(m+1,B,n)$ is such that $\exists t \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)$ so that  $t \upharpoonright n = s$, then $H_{(m+1)n}(s) = x \in A$ is the $\triangleleft$-least element in $B$ such that $s \frown \langle x \rangle \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)$. Then it follows (unless I am mistaken), that \begin{align*}
&\{s \in A^n: \exists t \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)(t \upharpoonright n = s)\}\\
&=\{s \in A^n: \exists t \in \text{En}(i,B,n+1)(t \upharpoonright n = s) \cap A^{n+1}(t \upharpoonright n = s)\}.
\end{align*}
But this is exactly $\text{En}(m+1,A,n)$ by $(1)$!
Is the idea here correct?
